# How to multithread URL requests in python 2.6 using 'pycurl' and 'threading' modules?

Tags: linux, apache, python-multithreading, python-2.6, pycurl

I am on python 2.6
HTTPD 2.2.15
CentOS 6

I am writing a python script that involves making a lot of REST API calls. I decided to try increase the speed of the program by multi-threading the URL requests. I used the requests module and everything worked fine. I had to switch to pycurl so I copied pycurl code I had that works.

Now when I run the code I get errors in some threads sometimes. Not the same threads everytime. By commenting out all the threads except 1 I cannot reproduce the error, but all it takes is 2 or more threads for the errors to potentially show up.

I can't share the exact code, but here is an approximation:

```
import os
import datetime
import time
import pycurl
import threading
from StringIO import StringIO
from pprint import pprint as pprint
import json

variable1 = {}
variable2 = {"x": {}, "y": {}}

def pycurl_method(url, creds):
  buffer = StringIO()
  c = pycurl.Curl()
  c.setopt(c.URL, url)
  c.setopt(c.USERPWD, creds[0] + ':' + creds[1])
  c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
  c.perform()
  c.close()
  response = buffer.getvalue()
  return json.loads(response)

def url_method(url, creds):
  env = threading.current_thread().getName()
  response = pycurl_method(url, creds)
  ...Do stuff...

def start_threads(threads):
  for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

def join_threads(threads):
  for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

def main():
  apiUrl0 = "some URL"
  apiUrl1 = "some different URL"
  apiUrl2 = "etc"
  ...

  creds = #returns credentials from a file stored on the server as [username,password]

  #Multithread API calls
  t0 = threading.Thread(target=url_method, name='nameOfThread0', args=(apiUrl0, creds))
  t1 = threading.Thread(target=url_method, name='nameOfThread1', args=(apiUrl1, creds))
  t2 = threading.Thread(target=url_method, name='nameOfThread2', args=(apiUrl2, creds))
  ...

  start_threads([t0, t1, t2, ...etc...])
  join_threads([t0, t1, t2, ...etc...])
```

Errors are like this:
File "this_script.py", line xyz, in url_method
  c.perform()
error: (77, 'Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)')

If I remove the threads and execute sequentially, I get no errors.
I think It might be related to pycurl (since requests was fine).
Specifically, pycurl.Curl().
I wonder if each thread is somehow using the same pycurl.Curl() and stepping on the toes of other threads.

Why do these errors show up?
How can I avoid them?
Do the threading and pycurl modules not play nicely together?

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted originates in libcurl. Python 2.6 has been end of lifed years ago, how old are your pycurl and libcurl? Start by upgrading libcurl and pycurl to current versions.

Comment: I am in an environment where I cannot update. If I was in an environment where I could update I would not use 2.6.

Comment: You can try compiling your own libcurl and pycurl in this case. It's not easy but certainly doable.